# How can I add a variable amount of columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which I apply it on the rows of a dataframe. This function returns a list of variable length depending on a parameter.

For now I use the following example code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

def add_columns(x, amount):
    return range(amount)

df["L1"], df["L2"], df["L3"] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: add_columns(x, 3), axis=1))
```

Is there a way to add the labels automatically ?

Comment: Your original code isn't working for me. what version of pandas are you using? Why aren't you using `df.apply(...).T` instead of `zip(*...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly in what you want to populate your columns with but this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def add_columns(x, *args):
    col_names = args[0]
    return pd.Series({i: x for i in col_names})

def add_range(x, *args):
    col_names = args[1]
    return pd.Series({k: v for k,v in zip(args[1],range(args[0]))})

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(10,2)),columns=["A","B"])

labels = ["L1","L2","L3"]

# This populates with values from "A" column
df.merge(df["A"].apply(add_columns, args=([labels])),left_index=True, right_index=True)

# This populates with values from range(number_passed) function
df.merge(df["A"].apply(add_range, args=([3,labels])),left_index=True, right_index=True)
```